# Background image is not showing in css

Tags: html, css, image

I have searched on the internet and found that setting `body, html` `height, width` to 100% will fix the issue but it did not.
I have this html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container index">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="buttons">

                <!--learn alphabets button-->
                <a>
                    <div class="col-3 learn">
                        <p>
                            Learn
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div><!--buttons end here-->
        </div><!--row ends here-->
    </div><!--container ends here-->

</body>
```

and in my css:

```
.index{
    background-image: url("../images/index-bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I have defined the width and height to body and html:

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

but the image is not showing up unless I set the height of `.index` in `px`.
Why is that so?

Comment: You can use percents, .index (container) should cover whole page, right?

Comment: @nevermind yes it should

Comment: Ok, container will not 'inherit' parent properties, set height to 100% and that should be ok, or, simple, put image background to body.

Comment: Why not apply the background image to the body tag instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a height applied to your `.index` div. The background will only be as tall as the content that div contains.

```
.index {
    background-image: url("../images/index-bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Stretch the `.index` container as well to fill the space of the body, otherwise it will only be as tall as the content inside.

```
 html,
 body {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .index {
     background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500");
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/64917998/1/**

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your `.index` class a height. Either a static or dynamic.

```
.index{
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url("../images/index-bg.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/thnszsh1/)

Comment: `background-size: cover;` then what does it do then? :/

Comment: it sets the background so that it always covers the entire width of the picture. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: @Adamnick `background-size: cover;` enlarges the background-image at its original ratio until the full width & height of the element are covered by the image. You still need to designate a size of the element however.