# google maps height 100% of div parent

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Is it possible make a google map height 100% of the parent div?
I noticed that with the height 100%, the map is not visible, but if I add the height of the div with the map in pixel the map is correctly visualize.
is there some tricks to achieve the map 100% of the parent div?
this doesn't works

```
<div class="block halfrect">
    <div id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

this works

```
    <div class="block halfrect">
        <div id="map" style="height:590px;"></div>
    </div>
```

any idea?

Comment: How are you connecting the Map? Using iframe or javascaript?

Comment: javascript, google api v3

Comment: post the solution you found, and accept it as answer so others can use your solution

Comment: I added these rules to the div map:  "display: block; position:absolute; height:auto;" and now works

Comment: Your question seems similar to this one. Your block halfrect class has no height associated with it, so the map fills up 100% of nothing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927894/background-image-is-not-showing-in-css/32927985#32927985

Comment: my halfrect have an height, I found the solution to the problem, as I wrote before... thanks anyway

Answer (score 7):

[reference: Mike Williams' Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial page: Using a percentage height for the map div](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

> If you try to use style="width:100%;height:100%" on your map div, you get a map div that has zero height. That's because the div tries to be a percentage of the size of the `<body>`, but by default the `<body>` has an indeterminate height.
>   There are ways to determine the height of the screen and use that number of pixels as the height of the map div, but a simple alternative is to change the  so that its height is 100% of the page. We can do this by applying style="height:100%" to both the `<body>` and the `<html>`. (We have to do it to both, otherwise the `<body>` tries to be 100% of the height of the document, and the default for that is an indeterminate height.)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="block halfrect" style="height:100%">
  <div id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```