# Width and height of the Google map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to Set the Width and the height of the google map. I want to make it larger on the html page. I am trying to change the styles but the widht and height of the maps is not changing. it seems that my styles are not affecting the map. Can anyone help  me to fix the issue

Here is the code

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <!-- Style Sheets includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
    html, body, #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
        position: relative;
    }
    </style>
        <link href="css/customstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Script includes -->
        <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.14" src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
        <script src="#"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <script src="data.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="ApplicationController as appctrl">
        <div class="container">

<div id="map" ></div>

  </div>
 </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: There is no map code in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps height 100% of div parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928684/google-maps-height-100-of-div-parent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the div map is inside other div (eg: container) all the parent div must have an height and width setted .. in your case the

```
<div class="container">
```

is not setted

try this way

```
html, body, .container,  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map {
    position: relative;
}
```

code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, .container,  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div id="map"></div>

</div>
```