# Why can't I see my map shown on my page? it's only happens when i add a Css format

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

hi I need help to show a map into my web page I don't know for what reason i cannot display the map, below my code I update google secret key:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include '../../WSweb/serv.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) )  
{
  if ($_SESSION["id"]==1)
  {
    $ID_Bodega=$_SESSION["ID_Bodega"];

        include ("../conexion.php");
        $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `tabla`.`Datos` where `Datos`.`ID_Bodega`='$ID_Bodega' ");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {

            $lat=$row['latitud'];
            $lng=$row['longitud'];

        }
        //mysqli_close($bd);

?>
<?php require_once('../../Connections/catalogo.php'); ?>
<html lang="es">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=Cambiar aqui"></script>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" 
</script>
-->
<title>Pedidos</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<link href="../../CSS/styles/eCommerceStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    //var pint=new google.maps.LatLng(20.6416592,-103.3492883);
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat.', '.$lng; ?>),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });    
    downloadUrl("../../Bodega/mark3.php", function(data) {
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      var mark3 = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < mark3.length; i++) {
      var name = mark3[i].getAttribute("ID_Bodega");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(mark3[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(mark3[i].getAttribute("lng"))
          );
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point
        //,center:point
        , map: map
        ,});
      }
    });
    downloadUrl("../../Bodega/markers.php", function(data) {
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var icon = '../../Bodega/marker1.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: point,
          icon: icon
        });
       var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<a href="../../Bodega/mostrar?recordID='+name+'">ver '+name+'</a>'});
        popup.open(map, marker);
      }
    });

  }
  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }
  function doNothing() {}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><div class="headerint"><!-- end .header --><img src="../logo.jpg" width="200" height="33" alt="logo" /></div></div>
  <div class="subcontenedor">
  <div class="sidebar1">
   <?php include("../Includes/Admin.php"); 
      ?>
    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>
  <div
 class="content" onload="load()" ><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="contenido" -->
  <h1> Mapa</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    <!-- end .content --></div>
     </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <?php include("../Includes/foot.php"); 
      ?>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script> window.location="../index"; </script>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<script> window.location="../index"; </script>';
}
?>
```

and this is the CSS, to be honest i suppose that the problem it's in the Css but i dont have idea:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
  font: 90%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #42413C;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
}


ul, ol, dl { 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin-top: 0;  
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;    }
a img { 
  border: none;
}

a:link {
  color: #42413C;
  text-decoration: underline; 
}
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { 
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: #954a9a;
}
.sidebar1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e2a5e6;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.content {

  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 780px;
  float: left;
}
.content ul, .content ol { 
  padding: 0 15px 15px 40px;
}
ul.nav {
  list-style: none; 
  border-top: 1px solid #666; 
  margin-bottom: 15px; 
}
ul.nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
ul.nav a, ul.nav a:visited {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 160px;  
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #C6D580;
}
ul.nav a:hover, ul.nav a:active, ul.nav a:focus { 
  background: #ADB96E;
  color: #FFF;
}

.footer {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #954a9a;
  position: relative;
  clear: both; 
}

.fltrt { 
  float: right;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { 
  clear:both;
  height:0;
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
#info {
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666666;
    border: solid 1px #666666;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 3px;

}
#enviar {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px 60px;
    padding:3px 10px 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
#respuesta {
    margin: auto 60px;
}
#googleMap {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    border: 2px solid #666666; 
    border-radius: 6px;
}
#map {
    margin: 10px auto;
    /* width: 90%; */
    height: 80%;
    border: 2px solid #666666;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.titular {
        background: #ffffff;
        font-size: 32px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 40px auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
        padding:3px 10px 3px 10px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: solid 1px #999999;
    }
```

NOTE: Obviously change the secret key and if I try a blank html the map works, somebody  can helps on this problem I will appreciate it very much

I attached an image that you can see the final result that i have, I never see the map :(

Comment: Why do you provide a snippet that only contains a portion of your code? Why does your script contain PHP that prevents anyone from running your code? What have you tried to fix the issue? Did you try debugging anything? Do you get any error in the js console? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map isn't showing on Google Maps JavaScript API v3 when nested in a div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349476/map-isnt-showing-on-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-when-nested-in-a-div-tag)

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps height 100% of div parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928684/google-maps-height-100-of-div-parent)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure parents of #map element is has enough width and height to display the map.

adding the code below in your CSS will help:

```
#map {
min-width:500px;
min-height:500px;
}
```